# I want to subtract values from two SQL selects

Tags: sql

I'm trying to subtract these two selects (two counts - the total unique phone numbers):

```
select
    count(distinct phnumber) as UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL
from
    (select
         month(c.callinfodate) as bMONTH,
         year(c.callinfodate) as bYEAR,
         c.phnumber,
         count(distinct c.idofthecallinfo) as TOTALcallinfoS,
         ses.applicationname, ele.typename
     from
         callinfo c
     left join
         sessioninfo ses on c.idofthecallinfo = ses.idofthecallinfo
     left join
         elementinfo ele on c.idofthecallinfo = ele.idofthecallinfo
     where
         ses.applicationname in ('CALLS_1', 'CALLS_2', 'CALLS_3', 'CALL_4')
    group by
        c.callinfodate, c.phnumber, ses.applicationname, ele.typename) as IVRTOTAL
group by
    bMONTH, bYEAR


select
    count(distinct phnumber) as UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL
from
    (select
         month(c.callinfodate) as bMONTH,
         year(c.callinfodate) as bYEAR,
         c.phnumber,
         count(distinct c.idofthecallinfo) as TOTALcallinfoS,
         ses.applicationname, ele.typename
     from
         callinfo c
     left join
         sessioninfo ses on c.idofthecallinfo = ses.idofthecallinfo
     left join
         elementinfo ele on c.idofthecallinfo = ele.idofthecallinfo
     where
         ((ses.applicationname in ('CALLS_4')
          and ele.typename in ('CALLS_41', 'CALLS_42', 'CALLS_43', 'CALLS_44',
                               'CALLS_45', 'CALLS_46', 'CALLS_47')))
     group by
         c.callinfodate, c.phnumber, ses.applicationname, ele.typename) as IVRTOTAL
group by
    bMONTH, bYEAR
```

The result from the first query is:

```
UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL
---------------------
11219
153041
149043
143166
138100
8343
```

The result from the second query is:

```
4007
68528
63922
61037
60494
3276
```

The expected result:

```
7212
84513
85121
82129
77606
5067
```

I tried many ways and checked other sections like mine, but I couldn't find the right solution.

I tried to subtract with using of JOIN between two selects, but I received more rows than I expected.

The result now:

```
7212
7943
-49818
-52703
-57309
-49275
149034
149765
92004
89119
84513
92547
145036
145767
88006
85121
80515
88549
139159
139890
82129
79244
74638
82672
134093
134824
77063
74178
69572
77606
4336
5067
-52694
-55579
-60185
-52151
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without completely rewriting the query, you could just join the 2 results on month/year to match up the values.

```
select  t1.UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL - t2.UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL
from    (
    select      count(distinct phnumber) as UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL
              , bMONTH
              , bYEAR
    from        (
        select      month(c.callinfodate)             as bMONTH
                  , year(c.callinfodate)              as bYEAR
                  , c.phnumber
                  , count(distinct c.idofthecallinfo) as TOTALcallinfoS
                  , ses.applicationname
                  , ele.typename
        from        callinfo    c
        left join   sessioninfo ses on c.idofthecallinfo = ses.idofthecallinfo
        left join   elementinfo ele on c.idofthecallinfo = ele.idofthecallinfo
        where       ses.applicationname in ('CALLS_1', 'CALLS_2', 'CALLS_3', 'CALL_4')
        group by    c.callinfodate
                  , c.phnumber
                  , ses.applicationname
                  , ele.typename
    ) as IVRTOTAL
    group by    bMONTH
              , bYEAR
) t1
join    (
    select      count(distinct phnumber) as UniquePHNUMBERS_TOTAL
              , bMONTH
              , bYEAR
    from        (
        select      month(c.callinfodate)             as bMONTH
                  , year(c.callinfodate)              as bYEAR
                  , c.phnumber
                  , count(distinct c.idofthecallinfo) as TOTALcallinfoS
                  , ses.applicationname
                  , ele.typename
        from        callinfo    c
        left join   sessioninfo ses on c.idofthecallinfo = ses.idofthecallinfo
        left join   elementinfo ele on c.idofthecallinfo = ele.idofthecallinfo
        where       ((
                            ses.applicationname in ('CALLS_4')
                  and       ele.typename in ('CALLS_41', 'CALLS_42', 'CALLS_43', 'CALLS_44', 'CALLS_45', 'CALLS_46', 'CALLS_47')
                    )
        )
        group by    c.callinfodate
                  , c.phnumber
                  , ses.applicationname
                  , ele.typename
    ) as IVRTOTAL
    group by    bMONTH
              , bYEAR
) t2 on   t2.bMONTH = t1.bMONTH
     and  t2.bYEAR = t1.bYEAR
```

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN preferred here

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev  maybe.  Could prefer left join as well.  May never know.

Comment: I try this and it's working. 10X bro

Answer (score 0):

Because both your queries are grouped by month and year, you can join them by those fields and subtract values;

```
with q1 as ( -- first query
    select month, year, count()
    from ....
    group by month, year
),
with q2 as ( -- second query
    select month, year, count()
    from ....
    group by month, year
) select
    coalesce(q1.year, q2.year) y,
    coalesce(q1.month, q2.month) m,
    coalesce(q1.count, 0) - coalesce(q2.cout, 0) diff
from q1
full outer join q2
```